# How do i add my maxDiff value to my ArrayList in this scenario?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

So in my findProfit() i have an if-statement: if (priceDiff > maxDiff). If that criteria is met i want it to set maxDiff = priceDiff which works as it should, but then i want it to also take that new maxDiff value and store it in my købtAktie ArrayList. That, i can't get to work, my arraylist just keeps returning "null". Can someone help?

```
public class ProfitCalculator {

static int minValue, maxValue, maxDiff;
static Calendar timeMin, timeMax;
static int indeksMinMinut, indeksMaxMinut;
static ArrayList<Integer> købtAktie;


public static void main(String args[]) {
    int aktiePris[] = new int[]{10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9};
    ArrayList<Integer> profit = findProfit(aktiePris);
    købtAktie = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("profit: " + købtAktie);

}

public static ArrayList<Integer> findProfit(int[] inputArray) {

    /*if (inputArray.length < 1) {
        return 0;
    }*/

    maxDiff = 0;
    minValue = inputArray[0];
    maxValue = minValue;

    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = inputArray[i];
            indeksMaxMinut = i;
            int priceDiff = maxValue - minValue;
            if (priceDiff > maxDiff) {
                maxDiff = priceDiff;
                købtAktie.add(maxDiff);
            }
        } else if (inputArray[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = maxValue = inputArray[i];
            indeksMinMinut = i;
        }
    }

    return købtAktie;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating a list after manipulation. This line:

```
købtAktie = new ArrayList<>();
```

should be invoked before this one:

```
findProfit(aktiePris);
```

Notice I'm not using any returned value - the method can be `void` as it operates on global variable (which is not very good but works).